# Проект в eclipse перемещается в локальный репозиторий

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

Есть проект в еклипсе, котрый строго должен находится в sdk папке. В bitbucket создаю новый гит репозиторий. Оттуда копирую ссылку (https://sss@bitbucket.org/sss/qwerty.git).

Теперь в еклипсе (egit) нажимаю на "Clone a Git repository". Далее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого расшариваю любой проект, а проект перемещается из sdk в локальный репозиторий и перестает работать? Что делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как вы явно указываете, что проект нужно клонировать в `G:\temp\qwerty`. Там он и оказывается. Укажите правильный путь к папке sdk вашего проекта.

Вообще, более удобный путь это:

1. Не клонировать пустой репозиторий с Bitbucket, а создавать его локально, а потом делать push на Bitbucket. Он даже инструкцию дает в пустом проекте:

   > Already have a Git repository on your computer? Let's push it up to Bitbucket.

   ```
   cd /path/to/my/repo
   git remote add origin https://YourName@bitbucket.org/YourName/repo-name.git
   git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
   git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
   ```
2. Работать через командную строку (git-bash, cygwin).